# How to reverse matrix vector multiplication?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, vectors

I'm using the simple `matrix x vector` multiplication below to calculate `result`. And now I wonder how can I calculate `vector` if I know `matrix` and `result` ? So when I multiply `matrix` and `vector` afterwards again I get `result`.

---

Sorry I don't know how you call this multiplication. I was never deep in those math topics. I have a program that does my calculation. I hope you can understand and classify the multiplication:

```
// float[] matrix = [4x4], float[] vector = [4] column vector

float[] result = new float[vector.Length];
for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        result[column] += matrix[column + row * 4] * vector[row];
}
return result;
```

**Update:** I found [this](http://www.cg.info.hiroshima-cu.ac.jp/~miyazaki/knowledge/teche23.html) for inverted matrices and I now remember mathematicians don't care for complexity of things but we programmers do. Is there no way to **avoid** matrix inversion (to lessen complexity) ?

**Solution:** I implemented the raw 4x4 matrix inversion and (alternatively) I inverted the matrix **generation**. In the end I got the very same matrices and the very same valid results for my vector. I choose the 2nd path because that reduces the complexity to around the same as the calculation done in my first sentence above.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ and want to find the vector $x$ which satisfies $$Ax=b.$$

If the matrix $A$ is invertible, then the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, namely $x=A^{-1}b$. If $A$ is not invertible, there may be either zero or many solutions to your problem.

Comment: Looks like a straight forward mathematician way to solve things. Is there a way around matrix inversion ? I ask because I'm not sure if the complexity is good for my application.

Comment: Well, any function you have that is capable of solving systems of linear equations will, at least implicitly, be a function that is capable of calculating matrix inverses. In general, I recommend you either use a library that can solve problems like yours or implement the LU decomposition for your problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Comment: @5xum Computing explicitly the inverse of a matrix is usually a bad idea if it is only to find the solution of an associated linear system of equations.

Comment: @Surb Yes, my problem is that the matrix is different every time.

Comment: Accepted for _mathematically correct_ and _answered first_. I inverted the matrix while generating it since it was possible for me.

Answer (score 2):

If one were to list 5 computational problems that are central to computer science, solving the matrix equation $Ax = b$ would be one of them. Here, $A$ is your matrix, $b$ is your result, and $x$ is the vector you are trying to solve for.

Regardless of what method you decide to use, you should be using a library and not manually coding the algorithm. There are two classical methods for solving the linear system $Ax = b$. The first is *Gaussian elimination*, suitable for small to medium-sized, dense matrices. This is implemented in NumPy as `numpy.linalg.solve`, or more generally, in LAPACK as `gesv`. Gaussian elimination, in all its implementations, are exact in exact arithmetic, and so you can never beat the $O(n^3)$ scaling.

The second is the *iterative method*, suitable for large, sparse matrices. There are several variations on this method. If $A$ is symmetric and positive-definite, you can use Conjugate Gradients. Otherwise, you will want to use GMRES. Actual library implementations of these are slightly more varied, and you will have to search the internet to find one suitable for your purposes. Iterative methods take advantage of sparsity to perform far faster than Gaussian elimination, at the cost of not being exact in exact arithmetic. However, given well-conditioned and sparse matrices, iterative methods have superb accuracy.

There is a third but less common option. If you know some special knowledge about the structure of your matrix, then you can also look for structured matrix solvers. Given the nature of your question, it is likely that this is not the case for your problem.

The bottom line is that you should search the internet to find a suitable library. If computational efficiency is very important to you, nothing that you come up with is going to beat the performance of subroutines in libraries like LAPACK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve a linear system of the form 
$$Ax = b,$$
you shouldn't compute the inverse of the matrix $A$. If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has no special structure it can need up to $O(n^3)$ steps to compute $A^{-1}$. This is only worth if you have to solve this system a LOT of times for fixed $A$ and differents $b$. Usually we use the [conjugate gradient method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) which provides you a solution in at most $O(n)$ steps. Think also at using some [preconditioner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner).
Anyway the best is probably to reproduce what the Matlab command $A\setminus b$ is doing and this can be found [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices).

Comment: Or, for a non-iterative method, he could use the LU decomposition. Seeing as the OP seems little trained in maths, it is a method much easier to understand.

Comment: @5xum Well I'm not sure weather the OP wants an efficient way to solve linear systems or to understand the known ways there are to solve linear systems. In the first case I think conjugate gradient is suited and not hard to implement (but to know what is happening is something else), in the second case then the way is long and yes LU is a good start after Gauss elimination algorithm.

Comment: I don't really understand why you push the conjugate gradient method over LU decomposition, especially given that MATLAB uses the LU method for non-sparse matrices and it works just fine... I think a direct method is, if applyable, favorable to an iterative one.

Comment: You are right, I always thought that Matlab was using systematically the conjugate gradient.